# Как правильно отредактировать запрос на удаление дубликатов?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Помогите разобраться, есть следующий SQL-запрос на удаление дубликатов:

```
DELETE from dbo.table_details
WHERE (table_details."type", table.id) in (
                SELECT table_details."type", table.id, count(*)
                FROM dbo.table
                INNER JOIN dbo.table_details ON table_details.id = table.id,
                group by table_details."type", table.ref_id
                having count(*) > 1);
```

он удаляет дубликаты в двух столбцах: `table_details."type"` и `table.id`, но удаляет как дубликаты так и сами строки (т.е. вообще все, если кратко), как можно исправить запрос, чтобы он удалял только **дубликаты**

Answer (score 0):

Схематично:

```
DELETE 
FROM table t1
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT NULL
    FROM table t2
    WHERE t1.{поля дублирования} = t2.{поля дублирования}
    AND t1.primary_id < t2.primary_id 
    )
```

Запрос удаляет записи-дубликаты по набору полей `{поля дублирования}`, используя любое уникальное non-NULL поле (например, автоинкрементный синтетический первичный ключ), оставляя запись с наибольшим значением в этом поле (типа самую "последнюю").

Можно использовать иное уникальное non-NULL поле (например, автоматически заполняемое `created_at`).

Если нужно оставить "самую первую" - поменять знак сравнения в подзапросе.

Answer (score 0):

Рассмотрите вариант, когда сперва удаляем все дублированные записи (полностью) и вставляем обратно только уникальные. Подходит, когда нет никаких столбцов, делающих строку уникальной.
Применимо, когда нет ограничивающих связей между таблицами.
Пример

```
create table test (id int,type varchar(10),descr varchar(10)
  ,dttm timestamp default now());
insert into test values
 (1,'r1','Rec1-1')
,(1,'r1','Rec1-2')
,(1,'r1','Rec1-3')
,(2,'r1','Rec2-1')
,(3,'r3','Rec3-1')
,(3,'r3','Rec3-2')
;
-- запрос
with d as (
  delete from  test
  where (id,type) in (select id,type
      from test t2
      group by id,type 
      having count(*)>1
     )
returning test.id,test.type,test.descr
)
insert into test
select id,type,min(descr) descr from d group by id,type;
```

Исходная таблица

| id | type | descr | dttm |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | r1 | Rec1-1 | 2023-08-21 11:09:19.651633 |
| 1 | r1 | Rec1-2 | 2023-08-21 11:09:19.651633 |
| 1 | r1 | Rec1-3 | 2023-08-21 11:09:19.651633 |
| 2 | r1 | Rec2-1 | 2023-08-21 11:09:19.651633 |
| 3 | r3 | Rec3-1 | 2023-08-21 11:09:19.651633 |
| 3 | r3 | Rec3-2 | 2023-08-21 11:09:19.651633 |

Результат (INSERT 0 2)

| id | type | descr | dttm |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | r1 | Rec1-1 | 2023-08-21 11:09:19.659016 |
| 2 | r1 | Rec2-1 | 2023-08-21 11:09:19.651633 |
| 3 | r3 | Rec3-1 | 2023-08-21 11:09:19.659016 |

Поля Descr и dttm - только для показа действий запроса. Они не обязательны.